How to get user account and widget information on WebOS web app?
I'm currently developing web app using WebOS SDK (Enact).
I want to show weather info from weather widget of WebOS native app on my web app, and also the user info including user name and email.
I couldn't find any relevant Luna services or other APIs.
Is there a way to get this information?

webOS's documentation doesn't seem to expose any kind of user PII. - which is just-as-well. I don't want any of my post-Enshittification Smart TVs knowing my e-mail address.
